# Replace URL in Text Body with an Image Tag for that URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

As the title suggests I would like to find a way to replace URLs within a body text (for a blog) with image tags for those URLs. I suspect I will need to do some form of regex. Has anyone done something like this before?

EDIT:
To describe the use case a bit more, I have a blog-esque site I am building. I would like blog writers to be able to 'drop' urls into text posts (separated by newlines), and have rails intelligently parse the string and replace any urls with images (perhaps in a helper method).

Comment: Can you give us an example of what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Whatever it is but don't use regex for parsing html files..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh god he didn't even say anything about parsing html

Comment: @akalikin I don't know where `body text`, `image tags` comes other than html or xml..

Comment: @AvinashRaj we both know what you're referring to, and there's nothing criminal about parsing **text** looking for links and surrounding them with `<img>` tag

Comment: To describe the use case a bit more, I have a blog-esque site I am building. I would like blog writers to be able to 'drop' urls into text posts (separated by newlines), and have rails intelligently parse the string and replace any urls with images (perhaps in a helper method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sanest approach is to use something like Markdown (or exactly like it) and ensure that your posts are marked up correctly. This seems to be the most up-to-date gem for Markdown, https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet.

Alternatively, if you want to do this by yourself, it would still be prudent to mark up a link in some way. For example, `{image src=link_to_the_image_here}`.

This will make finding images within the body of text easier.